# Multiple Bi-directional buses in verilog

Tags: verilog, can-bus, bidirectional

I am trying to simulate a CAN bus in a verilog test bench. I know I need 1 bi-directional bus for each node in the CAN network. What happens if many of the buses try to write a value in the bus at the same time? Will the dominant value of 0 win or will this produce some error? The code I am thinking of would go like this:

```
//First node
CAN_HIGH = (read) ? 'bz : DATA_NODE_A;
//Second node
CAN_HIGH = (read) ? 'bz : DATA_NODE_B;
```

If node A tries to write a 1 and node B tries to write a 0, will the value of CAN_HIGH be 0?

Comment: I think in this case you will receive a multiple source error on the synthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

in general, if you just drive a `net` type, i.e. `wire` from multiple sources, with the same value, the result will be the value you drive. If values are different, the resut will be **x**. `z` is a special case and is the weakest value and will be overwritten.

```
wire bus;
assign bus = en1 ? val1 : `z;
assign bus = en2 ? val2 : `z;
```

if both, `en1, en2` are down, the bus will have value of `z`;

if `en1` or `en2` , but not both are up, the bus will be assignd the  corresponding value (1 or 2).

if both, `en1` and `en2` are high, then, if `val1 == val2`, the bus will get the value of `val1/val2`, otherwise it would be `x`.

Now, in verilog you can define such a thing as an assignment strength, which is non-synthesizable, but can be used to behavioral modeling of certain situations, or in testbench. This would tell the verilog which assignment should win in the competition. There are several levels of strengthness in verilog, you can find it in documentation. Here is an example:

```
wire bus;
assign (strong0, weak1) bus = en1 ? val1 : `z;
assign bus = en2 ? val2 : `z;
```

In the above example if both en1 and en2 are high, and values are different, the first assignment will have stronger '0' but weader '1', so that val1 will provide '0' in the resulting value and assignment2 will provide '1'. You can use different combinations of strength. However, if the strengths are the same, it will behave as in the first example.